# Detecting a click on Grid while row editor is opened in buffered mode

Tags: gwt, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I want to show the dialog box by clicking on a different row (with options to save changes or cancel).
When Editor is open, it will catch the click and is stoping the event propagation, thus underlying Grid does not get the click event and ItemClickEvent is not being fired.

Is it possible to detect a click on the grid row through extensions or another way?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to detect a click on the grid row through extensions or another way?

Technically speaking yes. E.g. GridFastNavigation add-on does this trick in order to make possible single click editor opening.

But you could also listen to Editor opening, see (https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.3/8.3.1/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/components/grid/Editor.html#addOpenListener-com.vaadin.ui.components.grid.EditorOpenListener- ) when you are in unbuffered mode Editor already open, editor will re-open on the row you click. This catching this event could help you find a way.

Comment: Can you provide technical details or need to learn the way the add-on works?